select system call not returning stdin as set if used with other descriptors
int main() {
  fd_set readfds;
  fd_set writefds;
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_ZERO(&writefds);

  FD_SET(0, &readfds);
  int fd = open("random_path", O_WRONLY);
  FD_SET(fd, &writefds);

  struct timeval tv;
  tv.tv_sec = 10;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  int r = 0;
  string s;
  int i = 0;
  // Running loop 5 times
  while (i<5) {
    r = select(fd+1, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, &tv);
    cout<<"r is "<<r<<endl;
    if (r == -1) {
      cout<<"error"<<endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(0, &readfds)) {
      cout<<"reading from stdin"<<endl;
      cin>>s;
      cout<<"s is "<<s<<endl;
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(fd, &writefds)) {
      cout<<"writing to file"<<endl;
      write(fd, s.c_str(), s.length());
    }
    cout<<"sleeping"<<endl;
    sleep(5);
    i += 1;
  }
}

When I run this, the output I am getting is
r is 1
writing to file
sleeping
random text to set stdin fd
r is 1
writing to file
sleeping

as you can see, the code never goes in FD_ISSET(0, &readfds) since it never prints "reading from stdin", However if i change the select system call from select(fd+1) to select(1 or 2) i.e. anything less than fd, then I can see "reading from stdin"
qqq
r is 1
reading from stdin
s is qqq
sleeping


Reading the man page for select() should clue you in to a big issue with your use of the function.

Plain files are always ready for reading and writing.

but when the loop goes into sleep, I input a text on terminal, then stdin should also be set to be read from in next loop isn't it?
@Shawn just pointing me to man page doesn't help, ofcourse I checked that I cannot figure out which is why i posted

Note well the importance of thoroughly reading and understanding them.

@Shawn if you can specify the exact issue, I will appreciate it, otherwise its not helping and you are free to not reply :) ...I am also doing select for the first time

hmm, so I added FD_ZERO($readfds); FD_SET(0, &readfds); as part of re-initializing, and it works....but my understanding was that since FD_ISSET didn't return true, I did not need to do it since the fd was not ready anyways
and i did not have to do it with the other writefds, so I don't know why man page says I need to reinitialize all fd sets, when clearly I don't need to

You have to set the fdsets on each iteration.  All the fdsets are modified (destroyed) on each call to select().

so the reason I don't have to do it on writefds is because writefds fd is already set, so each iteration i would see it as set even if its not actually ready for some reason, since I did not re-initialize it, so ideally, i should be re-initializing all fd sets...correct?

It is always ready for writing, or nearly always, so it always gets set.

As Jonathan Leffler wrote in a comment on the question:

You have to set the fdsets on each iteration. All the fdsets are modified (destroyed) on each call to select().

Thus, adding
FD_ZERO($readfds);
FD_SET(0, &readfds);

as part of re-initializing, works.

Plagiarized from a comment. You must cite your sources, and not post others' work as your own.
